# pack hex string using struct module

Tags: python, struct, pack

I need to use struct module to pack hex string of '`4EA7`' to 2bytes, here is what I did:

```
struct.pack('<H',int('4EA7',16))
'\xa7N'
```

question is why it's not returning `\x4E\xA7`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for would be:

```
In [1]: struct.pack('>H',int('4EA7',16))
Out[1]: b'N\xa7'
```

`\x4E` in https://ascii.cl/ is the letter `'N'` an `A7` is printed as is.

Comment: Thank you! this '4EA7' string is part of an GUID string I need to write as  in BIOS  file. Does 'N' just how it printed, and not going to impact what is actually write into the file with the packe output?